# gwt/extjs - form not submitting

Tags: gwt, extjs

i have form tag received from designer.

i need to submit the form from GWT given below.

```
FormPanel form = null;
Button submit = null;
function onModuleLoad(){
  form = FormPanel.wrap(DOM.getElementById("MyForm"));
  form.setEncoding(FormPanel.ENCODING_MULTIPART);

  submit = Button.wrap(DOM.getElementById("OK"));
  submit.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
   public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
    // button clicked confirmed
    form.submit();
   }
  });


  formSubmitHandler = form.addSubmitHandler(new SubmitHandler(){
   public void onSubmit(SubmitEvent event) {
                    }

  });
}
```

but form was not submitted.

designer wrote the following lines.

```
form action="./a.cgi" method="post" name="MyForm" id="MyForm"

input type="button" value="OK"

form
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the form's submit button has an `id` of "OK"?  It looks like the button's `value` is "OK" but I don't see anything with "OK" as an `id`.

It seems weird though, since `DOM.getElementById("OK")` will return null if no element is found, and I'm not sure what happens when `wrap()` gets passed a null.

Check if `getElementById("OK")` is returning null.